# I don't understand why this redirect doesn't work

Tags: php

```
 if (lo_first == 'true' && $lo_first != '1') { 
header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
exit(); }
```

I don't understand why this redirect doesn't work

Comment: Have you output any content to the browser before this is called? Check error log...

Comment: Typo? `lo_first` vs `$lo_first`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `if`:

```
if (lo_first == 'true' && $lo_first != '1') {
```

Here you use both `lo_first` and `$lo_first`, which indicates that `$lo_first` is a variable from which the `$` is forgotten at its first use. Fix:

```
if (lo_first == 'true' && $lo_first != '1') {
```

Comment: Where would the fix be?

Comment: @SambathPiazza in the code you have shared in your question.